# Best practice Android package name and IOS bundleID

Tags: android, ios, bundle-identifier, package-name

Hi I am developing an Android app and one IOS app.

My question is regarding the Android package name and the IOS bundleID.

Is it best practice to use the same value on both platforms like `"com.mysite.myapp"`? or should I use different values for different platforms like:

- `"com.mysite.myapp.android"` on the android version
- `"com.mysite.myapp.ios"` on the IOS version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use names like `com.mysite.myapp.android` and `com.mysite.myapp.ios`. Additionally if app has different modules I prefer to give them some meaningful suffixes, for example `com.mysite.myapp.android.app` for app itself and `com.mysite.myapp.android.sal` for Service Access Layer (code that works with API).

But there are no strict requirements. You can name packages and bundles in any manner.

Answer (score 5):

You have **no boundation** on package name, **except** that package name **should not** be already on **play-store** or **ios-app-store**.

So you can make them same. or just use `android` or `ios` in package name for your convenience.

**Some additional info**

In Android **play-store-id** (defined in `build.gradle`) and **package-name** (defined in `manifest.xml`) can be different. So don't be confused in that.

You can put any Architecture or package structure for your classes and can set different package name for play-store.

Comment: Can error occur when using push with firebase or with other push systems?

Comment: Not at all, all systems have different mechanism written for android and ios.